# Que signfie "plaquouseuze" ?

Tags: sens

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> elle retrouverait rien de son sanfrusquin ! pas un oreiller ! pas une
> tasse ! ah, **plaquouseuze !**... plus une liqueur !... tout était
> liché, pourléché !... plus, ce qu'avait roulé à l'avenue !... et à la
> crevasse !... et sous l'ascenseur !...

Savez-vous ce que signifie *plaquouseuze* ?

Comment: Au passage, j'ai trouvé [ce dictionnaire](https://duclos.tripod.com/Dictiona.htm) qui compile des expressions et néologismes de Céline. Il n'y a pas tout mais c'est un début ! (je l'ai trouvé en cherchant sanfrusquin)

Comment: Par contre le site a l'air un peu mal foutu, par exemple pour accéder aux 'P' il faut aller sur la page `.com/P.htm`, qui n'apparaît pas en cliquant sur le P (`.com/Dictiona.htm#p`) ou en faisant défiler la page.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Mille mercis !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peut-être une coquille pour *[**planquouseuze**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/planquouser)* (dérivé de planquer: cacher).